# php call class function by string name

Tags: php

How can I call a normal (not static) class function by its name?

The below gives an error saying param 1 needs to be a valid callback. I don't want the function to be static, I want it to be a normal function, and all the examples I've seen so far had them static.

```
class Player
{
    public function SayHi() { print("Hi"); }
}

$player = new Player();

call_user_func($Player, 'SayHi');
```

Comment: read example 4 on their documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

Comment: I wonder that it is not complaining about the case. You are declaring "player" but calling "Player", with a capital "P".

Comment: @drale2k: It *is* complaining.  "param 1 needs to be a valid callback"

Comment: sorry, just a typo on this site on the P vs p. @Rocket, I understand that but was wondering how I would fix it in php syntax like the answers below provided me.

Comment: This worked for me, and shows several methods even suggests speed differences among them: https://www.designcise.com/web/tutorial/how-to-dynamically-invoke-a-class-method-in-php

Answer (score 137, accepted):

The [`callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php) syntax is a little odd in PHP.  What you need to do is make an array.  The 1st element is the object, and the 2nd is the method.

```
call_user_func(array($player, 'SayHi'));
```

You can also do it without `call_user_func`:

```
$player->{'SayHi'}();
```

Or:

```
$method = 'SayHi';
$player->$method();
```

Comment: Please is the third example identified with a particular name?

Comment: What is the second method called?

Comment: @Zack I know it might be a bit late, but for future people, this is called `variable functions` [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) and for variables is called `variables variable` [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Answer (score 11):

You need to pass the object and method together as an array:

```
call_user_func(array($Player, 'SayHi'));
```

See [callbacks](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php), specifically:

```
// Type 3: Object method call
$obj = new MyClass();
call_user_func(array($obj, 'myCallbackMethod'));
```

Answer (score 5):

I am giving my answer to a different question here ( [PHP - Can you assign a member function to a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436126/php-can-you-assign-a-member-function-to-a-variable) ), because it was marked as duplicate by some stackoverflow radicals, and I cannot give my answer to his question! The mentality of stackoverflow fanatics needs to stop.

btw generally this is anti pattern:

```
$a = 'Pl';
$b = 'aye';
$c = 'r';

$z = $a . $b . $c;

$myz = new $z();


$d = 'Say';
$e = 'Hi';

$x = $d.$e;
$myz->{$x}()
```

now spread out all variables across your code. You have become the anti christ.

why? because nobody can read your code any longer. Including yourself.

Better is to have the actual references in your code to the function calls you make. Not hidden in some obscure strings. No, just standard calls to the code, wrapped into a function.

Try to keep it as simple as possible. So a better solution would be this:

```
$x = function(){
  $player = new Player();
  $player->sayHi();
};


$x();
```

your IDE will find those references. `$myz->{$x}()` your IDE will not find and you wont be able to maintain well your code

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add an answer for people that have a class function that has arguments as well:

```
class Player{
    public function Say($what){ print($what); }
}

$player = new Player();
call_user_func_array( [ $player, 'Say' ], [ 'Hi' ] );
```

If you have more arguments in your function Player you can put them in the call_user_func_array's second array:

```
class Player{
    public function Say($what,$end){ print($what.$end); }
}

$player = new Player();
call_user_func_array( [ $player, 'Say' ], [ 'Hi','gh' ] );
```

Answer (score -1):

You are anyway creating an object of the class, so you can use object to call its function.

```
$player = new Player();
$player->SayHi();
```

or use callback

```
$player = new Player();
call_user_func(array($player, 'SayHi'));
```

Comment: That was just an example. I need to store the objects and their functions as callbacks, that will be fired from another system, but I didn't want to type that code out.