# PHP - Can you assign a member function to a variable?

Tags: php

In PHP5, variables can be evaluated as functions[1](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) such as:

```
function myFunc() {
   echo "whatever";
}

$callableFunction = 'myFunc';

$callableFunction(); // executes myFunc()
```

Is there any syntax for assigning object member functions to a variable such as:

```
class MyClass {
    function someCall() {
        echo "yay";
    }
}

$class = new MyClass();

// what I would like:
$assignedFunction = $class->someCall; // but I tried and it returns an error

$memberFunc = 'someCall';
$class->$memberFunc(); // I know this is valid, but I want a single variable to be able to be used to call different functions - I don't want to have to know whether it is part of a class or not.

// my current implementation because I don't know how to do it with anonymous functions:
$assignedFunction = function() { return $class->someCall(); } // <- seems lengthy; would be more efficient if I can just assign $class->someCall to the variable somehow?

$assignedFunction(); // I would like this to execute $class->someCall()
```

Comment: Yes, u can use call_user_function() method of php.

Comment: call_user_function() does not meet my requirements.. I still have to know what class and what function I am calling to use call_user_function(). I want to code ```$customFunc()``` call to be able to call any arbitrary function at runtime without prior knowledge in knowing whether it is a built-in function, a user function, a class static function, or a class object member function.

Comment: This question is NOT a duplicate of "php call class function by string name".

This question is about assigning a function/method to a variable so the variable behaves like a Closure.

The "php call class function by string name" is about using a variable string in place of the actual function/method name. The variable string does not behave like a Closure.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is a way, but for php 5.4 and above...

```
class MyClass {
    function someCall() {
        echo "yay";
    }
}

$obj = new Myclass();

$ref = array($obj, 'someCall');

$ref();
```

Hm.. actually it works for static too, just use the reference by name..

```
class MyClass {
    static function someCall2() {
        echo "yay2";
    }
}

$ref = array('MyClass', 'someCall2');

$ref();
```

And for nonstatic this notation works as well. It creates a temporary instance of the class. So, this is what you need, only you need php 5.4 and above )

Comment: Perfect! If you can find a php5.3 solution, please let me know. I may need to have some backward compatibility.

Answer (score 4):

The PHP 5.4 solution above is good.  If you need PHP 5.3, I don't think you can do much better than the anonymous function approach, but you could wrap that into a function that acts very similar to the PHP 5.4 method:

```
function buildCallable($obj, $function)
{
    return function () use ($obj, $function) {
        $args = func_get_args();
        return call_user_func_array(array($obj, $function), $args);
    };
}

//example
class MyClass
{
    public function add($x, $y)
    {
        return $x + $y;
    }

    public static function multiply($x, $y)
    {
        return $x * $y;
    }
}

//non-static methods
$callable = buildCallable(new MyClass(), 'add');
echo $callable(32, 10);

//static methods
$callable = buildCallable('MyClass', 'multiply');
echo $callable(21, 2);
```

This should work for any number of arguments to any (publicly visible) method.