# PHP curly brace syntax for calling methods using string

Tags: php, syntax

I saw in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16740152/683218) that one can use a string inside curly braces to call a PHP class method so that

```
$player->SayHi();
```

Can be alternative written as:

```
$player->{'SayHi'}();
```

My questions are:

What is this syntax called in PHP? and what happens if a wrong string that does not correspond to a method is used?

Also, can I use this syntax to call non class methods?

I looked at the answers in the linked post, and there is only links to PHP callback syntax, which does not seem to cover the curly brace syntax.

Thanks,

Comment: If it doesn't correspond to a method, you get an error, just like you would if you used the normal syntax.

Comment: In PHP when you call an object, you can access the method of object just calling by brace.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's part of [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php). When using variable variables or variable functions, you can replace the variable with any expression that returns a string by wrapping on braces. So you can do:

```
$var = 'SayHi';
$player->$var();
```

or you can do it in one step with:

```
$player->{'SayHi'}();
```

The syntax with braces is shown in the documentation of [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php). The example there is for a variable class property, but the same syntax is used for class methods.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also explain the curly brace a little bit? (when a string literal is used).

Comment: Like I said, you use curly braces when the value is an expression, not a variable. So you could do `->{$a.$b}` if you wanted to concatenate variables.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. Is there any PHP reference for using curly braces to bracket expressions in this case? Sorry for the newbie question. I just haven't seen this before.

Answer (score 1):

You can read about this in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Basicly:

```
function getVarName() 
{ return 'aMemberVar'; } 

print $foo->{getVarName()}; // prints "aMemberVar Member Variable"
```

Its a part of variable functions.