# Call object member function on all array members

Tags: php, arrays, callback

This may be a bit of a silly question and its one of convenience rather than functionality.

Assume we have the class:

```
class A { 
    public function getId() {
       return rand(0,100); //For simplicity's sake
    }
}
```

Let's say we have an array of objects of type `A`, e.g. `$array = [ new A(), new A(), new A() ];`

Normally if I want to transform the array of all objects into an array of their IDs I'd do something like:

```
$idArray = array_map(function ($a) { return $a->getId(); }, $array);
```

However this leaves me with a sort of burning desire to simplify this (I use it quite often). I would like a functionality like:

```
$idArray = magic_array_map('getId', $array);
```

My question is, is there a way to call array_map (or similar function) by providing the function name instead of an actual callback? Something akin to `array_map('count', $array)` but instead of `strlen` provide a member method name.

In short, is there such a way built-in PHP or do I have to implement an array_map of my own to add this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to apply technique [php call class function by string name (see final code snippet)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16740152/199364), into a function that maps that over the array:

```
function apply_member_function(string $method_name, array $array) :array {
    return array_map(function ($ob) {return $ob->$method_name();}, $array);
}
```

Usage:

```
$array_of_as = [ new A(), new A(), new A() ];
$array_of_ids = apply_member_function('getId', $array_of_as);
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you make your own function and pass it to `array_map()?`

```
class A {
  public function getId() {
    return rand(0,100); //For simplicity's sake
  }
}

$array = [ new A(), new A(), new A() ];

function getId(A $object) {
  return $object->getId();
}

$ids = array_map('getId', $array);
print_r($ids);
```

Comment: That's essentially what OP shows in the question; they just did it more conveniently (for a one-time use), by embedding the lambda function directly in the `array-map` call. What OP is looking for, is a way to *not have to write their own function each time*. That is, next time they want to call a *different* function, hence the mention of passing in *the name of the member function*.

Comment: [If you are calling the *same* member function many times, then an alternative solution is a function that performs the entire task: `function getIds(array $array_of_a) { return array_map(function ($a) { return $a->getId(); }, $array_of_a)); }`.  Usage: `$ids = getIds($array);`]

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view an elegant solution would be to create a Container class which would have a map method inside. Something like:

```
class A { 
    public function getId() {
       return rand(0,100); //For simplicity's sake
    }
}

class Container
{
    protected $elements;

    public function __construct($elements = array())
    {
        $this->elements = $elements;
    }

    public function map($method)
    {
        return array_map(function ($element) use ($method) {
            return $element->$method();
        }, $this->elements);
    }
}

$container = new Container([new A(), new A(), new A()]);

var_dump($container->map('getId'));
```

The result would be something like:

```
array(3) { [0]=> int(70) [1]=> int(32) [2]=> int(90) }
```

Comment: I like this. It's not exactly what I was looking for, but it's an elegant object-oriented approach.

Comment: **I recommend against this, from personal experience** at my company, making our own array-like class. The downside of making your own class, *that isn't a php array*, is a) you lose the convenience of built-in functionality that works with arrays, [you can restore *most* of that by implementing `ArrayAccess, Countable` and optionally `IteratorAggregate`] b) **future confusion by maintainers**: sometimes you'll inevitably be working with arrays, other times with your own class. This is bad, in a loosely-typed language like php.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own helper function to do what you want.

```
my_map_function($callback, $array) {
    return call_user_func_array(callback, $array);
}

my_callback_function($array) {
  //TODO
}

main() {
  $array = [1, 2, 3];
  $array = my_map_function('my_callback_function', $array);
}
```

Something like this ;)

Here you have more [information](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php)

Comment: I may not have explained it properly. The problem is that the callback function itself is a member function of each object in the array. I'll add some more info in the question.