# Running a method from array value

Tags: php, arrays, oop

I have an array populated by several class methods such that, I can randomly call some those methods for testing. 
The code below is what I'm trying to make work, but, I'm only getting the name of the method, it's not executed.

For example, lets say `1` is returned to `$methodIndex`, I get back `func2()` instead of `Hello Func2`.

Is there a function in PHP to do this or simple workaround?

```
class A{

    public function func1() { echo "Hello Func1"; }
    public function func2() { echo "Hello Func2"; }
    public function func3() { echo "Hello Func3"; }

    private $methods = ['func1', 'func2', 'func3'];

    public function get_methods(){ return $methods; }
}

$object = new A();

$methodIndex = mt_rand(0, count($object->get_methods()) - 1);
$object->get_methods()[$methodIndex]."()"; //e.g. $object->func2();
```

Comment: I think this will point you in the right direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740112/php-call-class-function-by-string-name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for [call_user_func](http://php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) (short array syntax shown)

```
call_user_func([$object, $object->get_methods()[$methodIndex]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be something along the lines of

```
$functionName = get_methods()[$methodIndex];
call_user_func(array($object, $functionName))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's it :-)

```
class A{

    public function func1() { echo "Hello Func1"; }
    public function func2() { echo "Hello Func2"; }
    public function func3() { echo "Hello Func3"; }

    private $methods = ['func1', 'func2', 'func3'];

    public function get_methods(){ return $methods; }

    public function random(){
        $method = $this->methods[rand(0, (count($this->methods) - 1))];

        if(is_callable(array($this, $method))){
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), func_get_args());
            }
        }
    }

$object = new A();

$object->random();
```