# Why does this example print twice?

Tags: php

When reading php documentation on variable passing, it seems this function is supposed to print

```
i am bar
i am bar
```

The documentation says; "When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc, variables are parsed within it."

function

```
<?php
class foo {
var $bar = 'I am bar.';
}

$foo = new foo();
$bar = 'bar';
$baz = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux');
echo "{$foo->$bar}\n";
echo "{$foo->{$baz[1]}}\n";
?>
```

Can someone help me understand

```
echo "{$foo->{$baz[1]}}\n";
```

Why does this also print 'i am bar'? And why is `$bar = 'bar'` declared and what's its significance? When it's deleted the file only prints `i am bar` once but I am not sure why since the second echo statement seems like it should be printing the $baz variable array?

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php call class function by string name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16740112/php-call-class-function-by-string-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you declare
$foo = new foo();
and then the $foo->bar is 'I am bar.'

So
the first time 'I am bar.'  is obvious.
the second time 'I am bar.' is a trick of php variable.

PHP will translate the following to

```
echo "{$foo->{$baz[1]}}\n";
```

==>

```
echo "{$foo->{$bar}}\n";
```

==>

```
echo "{$foo->bar}\n";
```

==>

```
echo "I am bar.";
```

That's why you got two line [I am bar.]

Comment: So the $baz variable was completely irrelevant?

Comment: Why exactly does it translate to 'i am bar'? Also, whtat is the significance of the second `$bar` variable? And why does it not print when the second `$bar` variable is deleted?

Comment: For avoiding misusing value, I will change $bar variable to $_bar.